# laravelcollective/html package installation issue in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm learning Laravel 5 and I want to install laravelcollective/html in Laravel 5.8.
I've found (here and somewhere else) couple of ways to do that. But, I've tried them with no success.
I'm using XAMPP 3.2.2 as local server on Windows 10.

### Solutions I've tried and what I got.

#### Solution 1

First, I've added this line

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.8.*"
```

to my composer.json's require array, save it. 
And, in my project directory, I ran the command

```
    composer update
```

#### Result 1

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\mylaravel> composer update
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

Above is a copy and paste of my terminal. The process stops at that level.

#### Solution 2

I've tried to install laravelcollective/html package by running:

```
    composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.8.*"
```

In this, I've tried some other arguments with **composer require**, like:

```
composer require 'laravelcollective/html:5.8.*'
```

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.8.*"
```

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.8.0"
```

```
composer require 'laravelcollective/html:5.8.0'
```

```
composer require 'laravelcollective/html:^5.8.0'
```

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html:^5.8.0"
```

Even an argument whithout indicating the version:

```
composer require  'laravelcollective/html'
```

All of them give the same result

#### Result 2

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\mylaravel> composer require 'laravelcollective/html:^5.8.0'


 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
 The "https://packagist.org/p/provider-2019-04%241d52886260d9f0e30a70676feea97a605da410b08fd409cad3de1a04bb47c878.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP
 /1.1 404 Not Found)

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

[image of solution2 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLZ37.png)

***Any help will be appreciated***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this version

```
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0"
```

Then perform

```
composer update
```

Comment: I've done it, but nothing.
After adding ** "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0" ** to my composer.json's require 
composer update 
And the process stops after 
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\mylaravel> composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Comment: It worked. **Thank you very much**. So, it should not have to be the same version as Laravel?

Comment: Latest version of laravelcollective "5.8.0" have installation issues